# Can Atlas on S^1 only contain one chart?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

The smallest atlas for the $S^1=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2|\,x^2+y^2=1\}$ must contain two charts. How to prove it?

My route is first to prove that it can only be homeomorphic to $
\Bbb R^1$ by invariant of domain (dimension). Then it restricts on mapping from $S^1$ into $\Bbb R$.

Secondly, I want to show such a homeomorphism cannot exist. But I got stuck, since I do not know how to partition a circle and **I noticed that the topological structure on the circle can be defined by those arcs on the circle with one end be filled one end be empty**. Then for the topology structure one should have a homeomophism eventually map$: (a,b]\rightarrow (c,d)$ which is not true. Then I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Hint: the circle is compact

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Brilliant! It could be the simplest proof that a circle cannot have atlas with one chart.

Comment: Sam's proof is also correct clearly, but the approach I suggested generalizes to all compact manifolds immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $U$ is any (nonempty) open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $U$ minus any point is disconnected. However, $S^1$ minus a point is always still connected.